# java class loader memory leak example

Tags: java, tomcat

I have found a very interesting memory leak example.

```
public class Misc {

    public static final String sql;
    public static String dbData;

    static {
        System.out.println("static started");
        sql = "select";
        dbData = GetDBData.execute();
        System.out.println("static ended");
    }

    public static String getDbData() {
        System.out.println("getDbData");
        return dbData;
    }
}

public class GetDBData {

    private String sql = Constants.mysql;

    public String getMessage(){
        System.out.println("getMessage");
        if ("select".equalsIgnoreCase(sql))
            return "dbData";
        return "nodata";
    }

    public static String execute(){
        System.out.println("execute");
        GetDBData myInst = new GetDBData();

        return myInst.getMessage();
    }
}

public class Constants {
    public static final String mysql = Misc.sql;
}

public class Main {

    static Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("GETDATA THREAD1");
            System.out.println("--------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started");
            System.out.println("--------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + Misc.getDbData());
        }
    };

    static Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("Constants THREAD");
            System.out.println("--------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started");
            System.out.println("--------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + Constants.mysql);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

If you run the code several times, the code blocks on static block of Misc class, but sometimes passes and the execution finishes.

In my struts based application code I have a jsp file who is calling Misc class something like this <% Misc.getDbData() %> and in Misc instead of sql I have MessageResources sqlResources.
After deploy sometimes 5 minutes is not working fine.(I got an error like this java.sql.SQLException: A character, token, or clause is not valid or is missing)

I'm thinking that, this might be the problem above with class loader, but tomcat is managing to solve the problem in the end.

possible solutions:

1. transform Misc class in a giant(I have multiple configurations here) singleton, and I have to refactor in more than 10000 places.
2. decoupling class Constants from Misc, but I still have another property based on system version.
3. Moving Misc.getDbData() from jsp into action would be a temporary solution for this? how thread for jsp/action are working?
4. do you have other solutions in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with memory leak.

As for solution, you should probably just do lazy initialization of `dbData`, so all classes can be initialized before creating an instance of one of them.

```java
public class Misc {

    public static final String sql;
    public static String dbData;

    static {
        System.out.println("static started");
        sql = "select";
        System.out.println("static ended");
    }

    public static synchronized String getDbData() {
        System.out.println("getDbData");
        if (dbData == null) {
            dbData = GetDBData.execute();
        }
        return dbData;
    }
}
```

---

***UPDATE:** Explanation of issue with question code.*

When a class is first needed, it will be loaded into memory, the half-formed class is locked, and static initializers start executing. During this time, the class cannot be accessed from another thread.

The question code starts 2 threads:

- In thread `t`, the classes are loading in order `Misc`, `GetDBData`, `Constants`.
- In thread `t2`, loading order is `Constants`, `Misc`, `GetDBData`.

It's now a **race condition**: If one of the threads completes initializing all 3 before the other thread gets there, then there is no issue.

If they run in parallel:

1. `t` will load/lock `Misc` and `t2` will load/lock `Constants`
2. `t` will load/lock `GetDBData` and `t2` will wait on `Misc`
3. `t` will wait on `Constants`

The threads are now **deadlocked**.

Comment: I will move all DB loading code in public static synchronized getter methods for lazy initialization. and I will ensure that getter is used for receiving data changing public static String dbData; to private. Anyway I don't understand why my presented code, blocks sometimes and sometimes works and how tomcat successfully recover from this.